How to drop retried events after x minutes in Firebase Functions 2nd gen
I am migrating some Firebase Functions code from 1st to 2nd gen. In my 1st gen functions I am using a shouldDropEvent helper which looks at the timestamp of the context and decides to drop the event after it has been retried for x minutes.
For 2nd gen I do not know where to find this timestamp.
Also, I would like to configure the retry behaviour, but I don't think it's possible with the current API.
The pubSendNotificationToUserToken is an abstraction I use for pubsub that keeps the topic and handler colocated in one place. Please ignore it.
import { pubSendNotificationToUserToken } from "@repo/core/notifications";
import type { EventContext } from "firebase-functions";
import functions from "firebase-functions";
import { onMessagePublished } from "firebase-functions/v2/pubsub";

const MINUTE_MS = 60 * 1000;
export const retryEventMaxAgeMs = 20 * MINUTE_MS;

export const sendNotificationToUserToken_1stGen = functions
  .runWith({
    failurePolicy: true,
  })
  .pubsub.topic(pubSendNotificationToUserToken.topic)
  .onPublish(async (message, context) => {
    if (shouldDropEvent(context, MINUTE_MS * 5)) {
      return;
    }

    await pubSendNotificationToUserToken.handle(message.json);
  });

export const sendNotificationToUserToken_2ndGen = onMessagePublished(
  {
    topic: pubSendNotificationToUserToken.topic,
    retry: true,
  },
  async (event) => {
    await pubSendNotificationToUserToken.handle(event.data.message.json);
  }
);

/**
 * Check if max age has been reached. Timestamp should be in RFC 3339 format to
 * match cloud functions context event timestamp.
 */
function shouldDropEvent(
  context: EventContext<unknown>,
  maxAgeMs = retryEventMaxAgeMs
) {
  const eventAge = Date.now() - Date.parse(context.timestamp);

  if (eventAge > maxAgeMs) {
    console.error(
      new Error(
        `Dropping event ${context.eventType} for ${context.resource.name} because max age was reached.`
      )
    );
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}


The onMessagePublished event handler receives a single CloudEvent typed argument which has a time attribute.
export const sendNotificationToUserToken_2ndGen = onMessagePublished(
  {
    topic: pubSendNotificationToUserToken.topic,
    retry: true,
  },
  async (event) => {
    // event.time contains the time of the CloudEvent argument
  }
);

